# Did not tick mark options during Ubuntu installation. [Read Detail]

Tags: installation, drivers

While installing Ubuntu, the first step was to select whether I want to download and install 3rd party updates and installations (codecs, etc.), which I had not selected that time because of slow internet. So now that it is installed, how am I supposed to get all those 3rd party softwares, drivers, codecs or updates?

I had not selected both the tick marks at the first step of installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Codecs

Install *ubuntu-restricted-extras* from **Ubuntu Software Center**. It contains all these restricted codecs, flash and staff.

### Drivers

#### Ubuntu 12.04

Search for Additional drivers from dash, open the program and it will show you if any of them are available.

#### For later versions of Ubuntu

Search for **Software Sources** in dash, open it. Now go to additional drivers tab and it will show available drivers.

### Updates

You will be informed about updates automatically.
You can also manually check for **Software Updater** from dash and update Ubuntu.

Comment: Done all the above, but I only have one question. That is, when I had installed Ubuntu earlier (with both options ticked), I had got GParted inbuilt, whereas when I installed it second time (without ticking) I had to download it from Software Center. Is it somehow connected to the first step of installation?

Comment: What version were you using the first time? Ubuntu had GParted inbuilt up to 10.10 but later the abandoned it.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 13.04.